# Cron trigger did not correctly run in Spring

Tags: spring, cron

I am working on my Spring configuration, and I need a trigger that runs on the first of every month indefinitely.

I had "0 0 0 1 * ?" running, but it did not trigger when the time came. I can create a cron trigger for every minute, and it runs fine. So this issue strictly has to do with the cron trigger.

After looking through expression generators, "0 0 0 1 * *" seems to be the same expression? But it's painful because I have to wait for 3 weeks to know if it will work or not.

Comment: Try `Spring-Batch` to schedule your task.

Comment: you can change your system date to future date for testing.